# Python can't find time module after I moved my application to different folder

Tags: python, module, plone

I have a strange problem after I moved an application to a different folder. I copied all files inside the old folder to the new directory and then tried to restart the application. However when I do so I get the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/zeoserver", line 24, in <module>
    import plone.recipe.zeoserver.ctl
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.recipe.zeoserver-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/plone/recipe/zeoserver/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/usr/local/Plone/Python-2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sys, os, time, cStringIO, traceback, warnings, weakref, collections
ImportError: No module named time
```

This is particularly intriguing as `time` should be a pre-installed Python package. What is also interesting is that after renaming the old folder to `xyz_old` I cannot start the application from there either.

What could cause such an issue?

Comment: You should ask this in our forum, community.plone.org. Please see plone.org/support on how to best get help with Plone

Comment: Hi @T.KimNguyen thanks for that tip! I will do so.